# How can make consumer group in spark kafka stream and assign comsumers to consumer group

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have one topic having name topic_1 and created 4 partitions. I need to read parallel in Kafka spark stream. so I need to make one consumer group and consumers.

Can you plz help how can I do this?

For now Kafka spark stream, one time taking one request from Kafka.

Comment: @mike its not working.                                                                                                               kafkaParams.put("application.id", "Recon-pipeline-stream");
 kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
 kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
 kafkaParams.put("group.id", "recon-consumer-group1");
 kafkaParams.put("num.stream.threads", "2");

Comment: You don't have to _"I need to make one consumer group and consumers."_ That's the job of Kafka Client API (provided you use the same `--groupId`) and Spark makes use of it (so you don't have to). How are you loading records from Kafka in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [KafkaUtils](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) from Spark, it automatically will take advantage of the number of Spark Executors * Cores per Executor.

So, if you have 2 Spark Executors, with 2 Cores for each Executor, Spark will automatically consume 4 topic partitions in parallel.

In Kafka Spark Streaming integration, the number of input tasks are determined by the number of partitions in the topic. If your topic has 4 partitions, Spark Streaming will spawn 4 tasks for each batch.

If you have 1 Executor with 1 Core, then the core will sequentially executes the 4 tasks (no paralellism). Whereas if you have 2 Executor with 1 Core each, then each core will sequentially executes 2 tasks (so parallelism is 2).

With 4 partitions you should configure any of the following, to achieve max consumer parallellism:

- 1 Executor with 4 Cores
- 2 Executor with 2 Cores each
- 4 Executor with 1 Core each